# Is there an analytical limit of the log of softplus function?

Tags: limits

Is there an analytical expression for $\lim_{z\to-\infty} \log \log(1+\exp(z))$

I need to calculate $\log \log(1+\exp(z))$ for some very small $z$ such that 64-bit floating point arithmetic would just give $-\infty$, are there any approximations that I can use?

Comment: What do you mean by "analytical expression"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $-\infty$, but we have the asymptotic approximation:
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\log\left(1+e^z\right)\right)
&=\log\left(e^z-\tfrac12e^{2z}+O\!\left(e^{3z}\right)\right)\\
&=z+\log\left(1-\tfrac12e^z+O\!\left(e^{2z}\right)\right)\\
&=z-\tfrac12e^z+O\!\left(e^{2z}\right)
\end{align}
$$